# View ignores alpha value after View.VISIBLE

Tags: android, button, view, alpha

I have a button ,with alpha set to 0.5, and its visibility is gone in the layout.

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/Button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:background="@color/black_color" 
     android:alpha="0.5"
     android:visibility="gone"/>
```

At some point, I wish to make it visible ( `Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ), but when I do - it's not half-transparent (0.5). It appears as if alpha is set to 1.

Comment: I have tried the code you posted and at my end it seems to work just fine, could you maybe post a bit of activity code?

Answer (score 23):

This problem is usually the result of having `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the parent view. The reason is that the layout animation of setting visibility also changes the alpha of the view and overrides the change made by `setAlpha`.

To resolve this you can either remove `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` from the parent or create a custom view to set the visibility in `onVisibilityChanged` like this:

```
public class AlphaView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = AlphaView.class.getSimpleName();

    public AlphaView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AlphaView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AlphaView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public AlphaView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(@NonNull View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);

        if (visibility == VISIBLE) {
            setAlpha(0.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what did for me, taking out `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` as it set alpha to 1 for some reason.

Comment: `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` was the culprit for me as well. Sounds like this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thanks Bro. Saved the day

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well. It seems to be a bug in Android itself. My solution was to avoid setting visibility, and to adjust alpha only. My view has a visibility of 'visible' in the XML, and starts off with the XML alpha tag value set to 0.0. Then, when I want it to be visible, I adjust the alpha programmatically:

```
        dimmerView.setAlpha(.15f);
```

I disappear it by setting the alpha again to zero. Theoretically, you might need to adjust various views position on the z-axis with bringToFront (and in the case of a button you might want to remove its listener when alpha is set to zero), but in my implementation it did not seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `Button` `Gone` to `Visible`, add Alpha of the `Button`

**like :**

```
buttonObject.setAlpha(.5f);
```

Comment: Tried that, it appears half transparent for a around half a second and then black (alpha 1 ) again.

Comment: is there any way that it updates in another part of your code?

Comment: Nope.. I had a text watcher on some edit text, that changed the color and opacity of that button. But I removed it.. I plainly call setVisibility(visible) on the button now.

Comment: that's good. Does still has the problem? You can post your text watcher for better under standing.

Comment: The problem persists even after removing the text watcher, so it's not related to the text watcher..

Comment: another way is remove your alpha code & add color with transparency like 50% of black is  "#7f000000". Or you need to post your code to understand more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105543/discussion-between-sayem-and-bvtp).